# how to cast tr1/array to std::string?

Tags: c++, string, casting

I wonder how to cast `std::tr1::array<unsigned char, 16>` to a `std::string`?

the compiler always complain, I've tried

```
std::tr1::array<unsigned char, 16> sss;
string(sss);
string asd(sss);
```

either does work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unsigned char` makes this tricky.  If you know that your system uses 2s complement 1 byte 8 bit `unsigned char` and `char`, and implicit conversion from `unsigned char` to `char` does what you want (these are not always true!), and your array buffer is null terminated (ie, characters after the first `0` one should be discarded), this function works:

```
template<std::size_t N>
std::string to_string( std::array<unsigned char, N> const& arr ) {
  std::string retval;
  for( auto c : arr ) {
    if (!c)
      return retval;
    retval.push_back(c);
  }
  return retval;
}
```

I included some paranoia about the possibility that the array might be "full" and be missing the null terminator.

If you actually want all 16 `unsigned char`, even if some are null, you'll want to use this:

```
std::string str( arr.begin(), arr.end() );
```

which should use implicit conversion from the `unsigned char` to `char`.

If implicit casting doesn't do what you want, and you know that the `array`'s memory is actually an array of `char` even though its type is `unsigned char`, you need to do some reinterpret-casting.

For the null terminated case:

```
template<std::size_t N>
std::string to_string_helper( const char* buf ) {
  std::string retval; 
  if (!buf)
    return retval;
  for ( const char* it = buf; it < (buf+N); ++it ) {
    if (!*it)
      return retval;
    retval.push_back(*it);
  }
  return retval;
}
template<std::size_t N>
std::string to_string_2( std::array<unsigned char, N> const& arr ) {
  return to_string_helper<N>( arr.data() );
}
```

and for the "entire buffer" case:

```
template<std::size_t N>
std::string to_string_2( std::array<unsigned char, N> const& arr ) {
  const char* str = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(arr.data());
  return std::string( str, str+N );
}
```

Comment: +1 for the second option, but the first one won't compile if `sss` is an array of `unsigned char`.

Comment: @AndyProwl Missed that `unsigned`.  Clarified.  I think I got the undefined behavior bits right, but not certain.

Comment: @AndyProwl - also won't compile if `sss` is an array of `signed char`. Only `char` works.

Comment: @PeteBecker: That's true, it's good that you pointed it out. I explicitly mentioned `unsigned char` because that's what the OP had

Comment: Thank you every one!! My array is like{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}, so if I stay with char, will it be easier? Because I concern about the memory usage, so I changed it into unsigned char...Now I need the string to use unordered_map...

Comment: @weeo What does concerns about memory usage have to do with `char` vs `unsigned char`?

Comment: @Yakk I need to store this kind of array as much as possible with limited memory. So if I change from char to unsigned char, it should cut the memory to half?

Comment: @weeo no.  Why would an `unsigned char` take half as much memory as a `char`?

Comment: @Yakk my bad....if I need to cast from char array to string, will it be easy? I need to put my array into unordered_map, but it only take string and I don't know how to write its type to make it sure, so I'm trying to cast it to string...The other post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112024/c-how-to-insert-array-to-unordered-map-as-its-key/17113743?noredirect=1#17113743

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, you know this cast is a copying conversion, right?

```
// if you want the whole fixed-size string including any nul characters
template <std::size_t N>
std::string fixed_array_to_string(std::tr1::array<unsigned char, N> const &array)
{
    return std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&*array.begin()), N);
}

// if your array is nul-terminated
template <std::size_t N>
std::string nul_array_to_string(std::tr1::array<unsigned char, N> const &array)
{
    return std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&*array.begin()));
}
```

The `&*` thing is ugly, and could be replaced with `&array.front()`.

You can generalize this to an array of any type, if you're sure interpreting it as a `char` is meaningful:

```
// if you want the whole fixed-size string including any nul characters
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::string fixed_array_to_string(std::tr1::array<T, N> const &array)
{
    return std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&*array.begin()),
                       N * sizeof(T));
}
```

Comment: Is dereferencing an `end` iterator legal?  And I think the `(begin, end)` ctor of `std::string` copies null bytes?